# Excel VBA - How to get data from multiple-array JSON into columns

Tags: json, excel, vba

I found a solution for parsing JSON, and it works fine for the presented example:

Here's the code:

```
    Sub Test()
    Dim jsonText As String
    Dim jsonObj As Dictionary
    Dim jsonRows As Collection
    Dim jsonRow As Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim startColumn As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("VIEW")

    'Create a real JSON object
    jsonText = ws.Range("A1").Value

    'Parse it
    Set jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonText)

    'Get the rows collection
    Set jsonRows = jsonObj("rows")

    'Set the starting row where to put the values
    currentRow = 1

    'First column where to put the values
    startColumn = 2 'B

    'Loop through all the values received
    For Each jsonRow In jsonRows
        'Now loop through all the items in this row
        For i = 1 To jsonRow.Count
            ws.Cells(currentRow, startColumn + i - 1).Value = jsonRow(i)
        Next i

        'Increment the row to the next one
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
    Next jsonRow
End Sub
```

And the JSON that is working:

```
{"rows":[["20120604", "ABC", "89"],["20120604", "BCD", "120"],["20120604", "CDE","239"]]}
```

However I need to parse JSON that has a structure like this:

```
 [{"Id":"2604","Price": 520.4, "State": true},{"Id":"2605","Price": 322.8, "State": false},{"Id":"2619","Price": 104.7, "State": true},{"Id":"2628","Price": 182.2, "State": true}]
```

That means, in this case, It should be 3 columns (Id, Price, Status) and 4 rows.

It should be easy but I am just a total newbie here..

Comment: That's not valid JSON. You're mixing array and object notation.

Comment: Robby Cornelissen: Sorry, I messed that up. Now it is correct.

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: The one I downloaded here: http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html

Comment: I tried the example [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/640780-parse-json-excel-visual-basic-applications.html) and it worked ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
Dim jsonRows As Collection
Dim jsonRow As Dictionary 

'...

'Parse it
Set jsonRows = JSON.parse(jsonText)

'Set the starting row where to put the values
currentRow = 1

'First column where to put the values
startColumn = 2 'B

'Loop through all the values received
For Each jsonRow In jsonRows
    'Now set all the values in this row

    ws.Cells(currentRow, startColumn).Value = jsonRow("Id")
    ws.Cells(currentRow, startColumn + 1).Value = jsonRow("Price")
    ws.Cells(currentRow, startColumn + 2).Value = jsonRow("State")

    'Increment the row to the next one
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
Next jsonRow
```

Comment: And on what line?

Comment: I got it, this line: ws.Cells(currentRow, startColumn).Value = jsonRow("Id")

Comment: Yeah, it is in cell A1 in VIEW sheet.

Comment: 100% sure. I tried: ActiveCell.Value = jsonText and it outputs the correct JSON

Comment: Apparentely jsonRows is not an array because it seems the error occurs when the for each loop is initiated.

Comment: @Totallama If I `Dim jsonRows As Variant` instead of `As Collection`, then it works.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Not for me:o(

Comment: @Totallama I meant `Dim jsonRow As Variant`; `jsonRows` works as either a Variant or a Colleciton in this case.

Comment: `Dim jsonRow as Dictionary` should also do it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok, now it doesn't throw error so that's great but it puts value only in the first cell and then finishes (B1: 2604)

Comment: Alright, it works now. There was a different problem with datatype. Thanks a lot for all your help!!